# NoneType Error on Instance Variables

Tags: python, class

I'm having a bit of an issue. For some reason, this class I'm trying to put together is throwing a NoneType error when, for all intents and purposes it should be responding properly as far as I can tell.

```
import re
import subprocess

class progEnv( object ) :

    hostName_regex = re.compile( '[a-z][a-z]prog[a-z][a-z][a-z]\d\d' )
    hostDomain_regex = re.compile( '(prod|dev|qa1|stag)\.company\.net' )
    hostNum_regex = re.compile( '[a-z][a-z]prog[a-z][a-z][a-z](\d\d)' )
    hostPrefix_regex = re.compile( '\w\wprog' )
    hostTier_regex = re.compile( '(web|app)' )
    hostId_regex = re.compile( '[a-z][a-z]prog[a-z][a-z][a-z]\d\d([a-z])' )
    hostEnv_regex = re.compile( '(prod|dev|qa1|stag)' )

    def __init__( self ) :
        self.hostnameProc = subprocess.Popen( 'hostname', stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
        self.fqdn = self.hostnameProc.stdout.read()
        self.hostName = self.hostName_regex.search( self.fqdn )
        self.hostDomain = self.hostDomain_regex.search( self.fqdn )
        self.hostNum = self.hostNum_regex.search( self.hostName.group() )
        self.hostPrefix = self.hostPrefix_regex.search( self.hostName.group() )
        self.hostTier = self.hostTier_regex.search( self.hostName.group() )
        self.hostId = self.hostId_regex.search( self.hostName.group() )
        self.hostEnv = self.hostEnv_regex.search( self.hostName.group() )
```

When I instantiate the progEnv class the program fails on the call to `self.hostName.group()` with an error of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 5, in <module>
    env = prog_env.progEnv()
  File "/prog/eclipse/workspace/PROG Management Command/prog_env.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.hostNum = self.hostNum_regex.search( self.hostName.group() )
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Any thoughts on what is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that the regex didn't match, so `self.hostName_regex.search(self.fqdn)` returned `None`. And of course you can't use the `.group()` method on `None`.

Comment: You were the first to respond and I just realized exactly what was happening. Time to take a moment and facepalm. I just realized the reason it is throwing the error is because I'm running it in a server that doesn't match the regex scheme. Ugh.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you are trying to access the attribute `group` of `None`. From the code line that is displayed that means `self.hostName` must be `None`. The regex search you used to initialise `self.hostName` must have failed to match anything.

BTW, you seem to not fully understand the error message. It isn't "throwing a NoneType error", it is throwing an `AttributeError`: the error message for an AttributeError shows you the type of the object and the type of `None` is `NoneType`.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.hostName = self.hostName_regex.search( self.fqdn )
```

This line sets the value of self.hostName to `None`, when `self.fqdn` is not matched by regex. Which is causing the error. Change the dependent lines to something like,

```
self.hostNum = self.hostName and self.hostNum_regex.search( self.hostName.group() )
```

just to check self.hostName before using its `group` method.